# выдаёт ошибку при использовании Custom_Widgets pyqt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, pyside

Я пытаюсь использовать в своём проекте QCustomSlideMenu из модуля Custom_Widgets, но на стадии `from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import QCustomSlideMenu`  у меня выдаёт такую ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HOME\Desktop\ZH design\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import QCustomSlideMenu
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Widgets.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .Qss import SassCompiler
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Qss\SassCompiler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . SvgToPngIcons import NewIconsGenerator
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Qss\SvgToPngIcons.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cairosvg
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, установив другую версию модуля